# Retail CDT (Category Decision Tree) in R

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am trying to analyze a big data of many retail store transaction, within a particular category.
My goal is to build a market structure tree, than will be based on shopper choices - what is the most/least important attribute (attaching a photo for example).

What is the right way to do it in r?
I thought about choice modeling using mlogit, but I can't understand how to decide the ranking of the attributes.[Pet treat category tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEmGV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am actually looking for code, so there is no code I can add /:

Answer (score 0):

If you have Customer or User Data I would recommend using a distance matrix based on odds ratio for product proximity in a category. This way you can see and interpret customer choices.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).